# PHP Regex Facebook Video ID

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have my facebook urls below (which are all facebook videos) and I want to get its id.

1. https://mbasic.facebook.com/TrendingInPhilippinesOfficial/videos/1722369168023859/
2. https://mbasic.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=1722369168023859&id=1388211471439632

Output must be:

```
1. 1388211471439632
2. 1388211471439632
```

I used this regex to get the ID.

```
preg_match("~/videos/(?:t\.\d+/)?(\d+)~i", $_GET['url'], $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

well it works at `#1` but at `#2` it doesn't work.

Any solution into this?

Comment: 1388211471439632 is just in the second link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want one regex for both link?

```
$link1 = "https://mbasic.facebook.com/TrendingInPhilippinesOfficial/videos/1722369168023859/";
$link2 = "https://mbasic.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=1722369168023859&id=1388211471439632";
$regex = '/(videos|story_fbid)(\/|=)(\d+)(\/|&)?/';

preg_match($regex, $link1, $matches);
preg_match($regex, $link2, $matches2);
```

Note the `?` at the end of the regex, which will allow to parse it without the trailing `/` or the `&`. If you want to only parse the id when there's both, remove the question mark from the regex.

The var_dump of `$matches` would be:

```
array(5) {
    [0]=>
        string(24) "videos/1722369168023859/"
    [1]=>
        string(6) "videos"
    [2]=>
        string(1) "/"
    [3]=>
        string(16) "1722369168023859"
    [4]=>
        string(1) "/"
}
```

And the var_dump of `$matches2` would be:

```
array(5) {
    [0]=>
        string(28) "story_fbid=1722369168023859&"
    [1]=>
        string(10) "story_fbid"
    [2]=>
        string(1) "="
    [3]=>
        string(16) "1722369168023859"
    [4]=>
        string(1) "&"
}
```

Comment: What if the link 1 doesn't end with '/' and link 2 ends with '/'

Comment: @Jacob I've added the `?` at the end of the regex to allow it if the link 1 doesn't end with a trailing slash. Also, if the link 2 ends with a trailing slash, it should still work.

Answer (score 0):

To get parameters from an URL you can use parse_url & parse_str functions.

```
parse_str(parse_url($link2)['query'], $array);
print_r($array);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [story_fbid] => 1722369168023859
    [id] => 1388211471439632
)
```